# Explicit Declaration for an object

Tags: c++, constructor

how can i do Explicit initialization for object in below code...

```
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;

class per{
    char *name;
    int a;
public:
    per(int x = 0,char *str = 0):a(x),name(str){}

    char* get()
    {
        return name;
    }
};
int main()
{

    per obj(100,"test"); // works fine
    // now if i want a explicit initialization for above how will i do?
    // example -- per obj = (100,"test");
    // but i am getting error or may be not aware how to use
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us discuss what is the actual problem in the commented code, i.e `per obj = (100,"test");`. This does not get initialized because, the statement is first evaluated for `100,` (I mean comma operator) and then initialization occurs.

so Now the assignment `per obj = (100,"test");` will be looking as `per obj = "test";`. This causes compilation error since the first parameter expected is an `int` not a `char *`. You should be lucky to get this scuttle issue as compilation problem. Just change the order of initialization in constructor and this would vanish.. Causing a major bug getting un-noticed.  Basically what you expect and how the compiler is treating the statement is differing in this case.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
per obj = per(100,"test");
```

The terms are **direct** and **copy-initialization**.

Your initialization is also explicit.

Comment: i need explicit...above code doesn't work...i getting below error 1>c:\users\badshah\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\practice\practice\smart_class.cpp(34): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'per'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Comment: @Badshah - You might try `const char*` in the class, because string literals are const.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports C++11, you can do:

```
per obj = { 100, "test" };
```

Comment: i tried that also but not working i am using visual C++ express 2010